# Error in R.NET "Error: package 'RMySQL' is not installed for 'arch = i386' "

Tags: c#, r, rmysql

When I am running an Rscript using the C# code I got the error that I mentioned in subject.  Actually the RMySQL package is correctly installed in my system (Windows 7 64 bit)and I am able to run the script from Rconsole directly. But when calling from C# code I am getting this error. Please help me to find a solution for the same. Thank you

This is my C# code

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
  using RDotNet;

  namespace hottopics_new
  {
   public partial class hottopic : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
        REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
        engine.Initialize();
        var hottopic = engine.Evaluate("source('E:/******/******/Rscript/hottopics.R')").AsDataFrame();
        var words = hottopic[1].AsCharacter().ToArray();
        var freq = hottopic[2].AsCharacter().ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(words);
        Console.WriteLine(freq);
        engine.Dispose();
    }
  }
 }
```

```

I am getting the error in the following place in above code
"var hottopic = engine.Evaluate("source('E:/******/******/R script/hottopics.R')").AsDataFrame();"

And this is my R script

`user_id = 39988
        library(RMySQL)
        con = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='****', password='****', 
        dbname='****', host='*********')
        # Add the text mining library for using the removeWords and stopwords functions
        library(tm)
        setwd("E:/*****/****/R script")
        sqlQuery <- paste("SELECT b.user_id,a.user_social_account_id,a.content 
                              FROM mydb.updates a
                              INNER JOIN mydb.user_social_accounts b
                              ON a.user_social_account_id = b.id
                              WHERE a.user_social_account_id IN (SELECT id FROM mydb.user_social_accounts WHERE user_id =",user_id,')',sep = "")
        updates <- dbGetQuery(con,statement=sqlQuery)
        dbDisconnect(con)
        words <- read.csv("stopwords.csv",colClasses = "character")
        # Convert the 'words' object from data.frame to charcter vector format
        words <- words$Words
        updates$content <- tolower(updates$content)
        content <- updates$content
        # Split each words in the content and saved in a character vector format
        content <-unlist(strsplit(content, split=" "))
        # Remove all the stopwords,numbers and symbols from it
        content <- removeWords(content,c(stopwords("english"),stopwords("SMART"),words))
        content <- gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", "", content)
        # Count each words frequency using the 'table' function and store the result in data.frame format
        word_count <- as.data.frame(table(content))
        names(word_count) <- c("Word","Freq")
        # Removing the blank character from the result that comes when removing the symbols and numbers
        word_count <- word_count[-(word_count$Word == ""),]
        # Order the word_count data frame in the descending order of Frequency of words
        word_count <- word_count[order(-word_count$Freq,word_count$Word),]
        head(word_count,10)`

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be the [known issue due to the way IIS handles environment variables](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/workitem/117). The issue linked to has a workaround kindly proposed by the reporter of that issue.

Please mark this as answered if the workaround solves this issue; questions with ASP.NET + R.NET are a recurrent theme.